# logout and login on windows 7 without user interaction

Tags: windows-7, logging

Upon operator request, we need to log out automatically from the current user and log in as another user. All this without user interaction or awareness. 
Of course, the new user login details can be provided. 
What options Windows 7 offer to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Windows relies on a component named GINA (Graphical Identification and Authentication) to ask the user for login credentials. The standard GINA supplied with Windows displays the usual login fields that everyone knows, but it is possible to implement a custom one. Nothing says that any user interaction is required: a GINA for your specific case might get the information about which user to login (e.g., from a protected registry location), and proceed with the login. The logout phase can be done by just calling a standard Win32 API function (ExitWindowsEx) to ask for a user logoff. Therefore, one option for your problem might be to implement a custom GINA DLL (generally in C or C++), see the [details in the MS SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380543(v=vs.85).aspx). They also have example code.

There is also perhaps a possibility of doing this via the [Remote Desktop Services API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383464(v=vs.85).aspx) (also used for fast user switching), however I'm not sure whether it allows programmatically logging in a user or not.

A very crude way to implement this might also be having VNC server (e.g. UltraVNC) installed as a service on the machine, and having a remove (or local) service connect to the VNC server and send [RFB packets](https://github.com/rfbproto/rfbproto/blob/master/rfbproto.rst) as if a user was typing a password on the login screen. I have some doubts about the reliability of this solution (imagine a scenario where the logout didn't work because of a stuck application, the VNC automated client would possibly start typing the login password in an open editor...)

However, I don't see any way of doing this without writing code.